# MAC address in PHP/JavaScript/.NET?

Tags: php, .net, javascript

How can I get MAC address with using PHP, JavaScript and .NET ?

Comment: Why would you want that? I don't see any reason why you need details of the users networking hardware. You can't get it with javascript though.

Comment: Why do you want this? Do you build an internal monitoring application for your intranet and you want to know the MAC addresses of monitored servers? Or do you build an ordinary web application and want to get the MAC addresses of your visitors? One is possible, the other is not.

Answer (score 1):

MAC Addresses are not sent in HTTP headers... and I can't imagine javascript has access to them. I think you're out of luck... but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you really need it.
Because there is no use of MAC addresses over internet, but on LAN only.
JS has nothing to do it, but some ActiveScript can get it but it will ask user permission to install and works on IE only

Comment: actually  somebody ask me and I have no knowledge about it. So please tell me how can  we get Mac Address ?

Comment: @Karandeep well, tell them they don't need it as well

Answer (score 1):

also, anybody CAN change his MAC address. if what you are trying to do is for security purposes forget about it

Answer (score 1):

You would need an HTA - HTml Application or a native windows program: http://www.google.com/search?q=Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration+hta

Answer (score 0):

you **can't** do it with Javascript or php , only with a locally ran application